# Monte Carlo simulation vs. Discrete event simulation

Tags: simulation, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

I'm trying to understand the difference between a Monte Carlo simulation vs. a Discrete event simulation. I learned from googling( [for eg.: https://bookdown.org/manuele_leonelli/SimBook/types-of-simulations.html](https://bookdown.org/manuele_leonelli/SimBook/types-of-simulations.html)) that Monte Carlo simulations are static and do not account for time. However, I know that "time" in Discrete event simulations is just a record of the events that change the state of the system. For example, when simulating a supermarket checkout line, every new customer arrival or departure is a new event , causing the clock to tick forward (unless I'm mistaken about this).Why can I not view a Monte Carlo simulation where say, I'm simulating data from a Normal distribution as the same as Discrete event simulation, and just treat each data point as a new "event"?
What's the difference between the data points in a Monte Carlo simulation and the arrivals and departures in a queue modeled using Discrete event simulation? What am I missing?

Comment: The page you cited gives food for thought, but I have doubts that its definitions are corrrect, canonical, or even in some cases necessary.